# How to create '.py' file in Mac

Tags: python, macos, file

I want to create just a python file (.py) in mac.

Without using Pycharm or other IDE.
I tried using `'TextEdit'` but it didn't work.

Comment: ".py" files are regular text files with a ".py" extension.. any way you have of creating a text file will do. For example, via command line with `touch myfile.py`

Comment: `vi` in Terminal?

Comment: Also, why the "ide" tag if you explicitly say without an ide?

Comment: @GPhilo: Could you please try this using 'TextEdit' and revert back

Comment: @VineeshTP I don't have a mac at hand, but that is besides the point. If for whatever reason TextEdit won't allow you to save files with py extension, use a different method, there's many.

Comment: @GPhilo: When try to create a file .py can not save this  - "You cannot save this document with extension “.py” at the end of the name. The required extension is “.rtf”."

Comment: Look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/415958/how-do-i-change-the-file-extension-with-textedit-on-osx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press Save

Save file as myname.py

Unless I'm missing something?

EDIT

TextEdit has separate plain text and rich text modes. You'll have to select Format > Make Plain Text or set the default format to plain text first.

Comment: 'You cannot save this document with extension “.py” at the end of the name. The required extension is “.rtf”.'

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/415958/how-do-i-change-the-file-extension-with-textedit-on-osx

Comment: ^this might be the issue

Comment: This comment helped for me, https://superuser.com/questions/415958/how-do-i-change-the-file-extension-with-textedit-on-osx

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal.

```
cd Documents
touch file_title.py
```

The file_title.py will be in your Documents folder.